# Empty DOM when user saves page from chrome browser menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net, angular, asp.net-core

My requirement is when a user saves the complete page from `Chrome > Menu > More tools > Save page as..` then don't show any data to the user when he/she runs the downloaded file on their local machine. This type of functionality I have generally seen on Bank sites only.

I have tried to find the event of chrome menu, tried to convert HTML into canvas, searched for any events in jquery and angular to empty the dom but to no avail. In Angular, I have seen one plugin ng2-pdf-viewer using that plugin if we are showing pdf data then on saving the page that pdf is not showing on the local machine.

What might be the solution for this? I am working on an Angular 7 project but its not mandatory I can even make this project on .net or .net core also. It all depends on the solution.

Comment: This is not a feature or something you just *do*. The save page functionality literally just saves the HTML source. The browser will generally also download referenced assets (images, CSS, JS) and rewrite the paths in the HTML so it pulls from local. There's nothing you can do, really, to obfuscate this, as the browser is just using the assets it has. If it doesn't work on banking sites, it's generally because they're so *poorly* written and design, not because they're explicitly disallowing this.

Comment: It's like the similar question of how to disallow downloading images. You can't. You made them publicly available, the browser has already downloaded them to display them. There's nothing you can do, after that, to prevent a user from saving them themselves.

Comment: Thanks, @ChrisPratt I have updated my manager on this. Now he is no more demanding about this functionality.